# Magento. How get data of current order

Tags: php, magento, checkout

On review(summary) step in checkout I need to get data of current order in Block/Abstract 
How I can get this?. 
For example I need address, which customer select in billing/shiping step.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$checkout = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
$billing = $checkout->getBillingAddress();
```

This way you can get your Billing as well as shipping address wherever you like to display at cart.

Comment: And how I could get selected address? When I use this code I get array of all customer`s addresses.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on checkout page then you will use this code to get current order data, actually before order is placed all customer info is stored in quote object.

So you can get quote object by this code `$this->getOnepage()->getQuote();` or

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()
```